# Condition inside a condition (short form)

Tags: php, if-statement

I have the following condition, which says that if `$img[$i]` is `true`, then an image will be created in the code:

`<?= !$img[$i] ? "" : "<div class=\"image\"> <img src=\"/images/1.gif\" /></div>"; ?>`

I want to add another condition that says that if `$center=true`, then a class called `centered` will be added to the image, so eventually code will look like:

`<div class="image"><img src="images/1.gif" class="centered"/></div>`

So basically this means putting another condition inside the previous condition, but I can't simply add `!$center ? '' : ' class="centered"'` in the middle of the code.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can 'put it in the middle':

```
<?= $img[$i] ? '<div class="image"> <img src="/images/1.gif"'.($center ? ' class="centered"' : '').' /></div>' : ''; ?>
```

But that is ugly, don't you agree? I now make the assumption you what to output the HTML code. Then I can rewrite your code into:

```
if ($img[$i]) {
  echo '<div class="image">'.PHP_EOL;
  echo '  <img src="/images/1.gif"'.($center ? ' class="centered"' : '').' />'.PHP_EOL;
  echo '</div>'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

I think that looks nicer, in the sense that it is easier to read.

Comment: I''m getting a syntax error with your first line, is there a type there?

Comment: Yes, I changed it... I didn't test it, there was a quote wrong... It's ugly. :-)